# Why simple jQuery mobile table shown transposed?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Put on page sample (and simple) table:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

No surprise in showing - header is a row, trs inside body - rows.
Look at this:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
Row 1 Column 1  Row 1 Column 2  Row 1 Column 3
Row 2 Column 1  Row 2 Column 2  Row 2 Column 3
```

Then trying to make table jQuery-styled - just add data-role="table" to table tag.
Surprise - table whown transposed: 1) head is column (!) 2) rows are columns.
Look at this:

```
Column 1Row 1 Column 1
Column 2Row 1 Column 2
Column 3Row 1 Column 3
Column 1Row 2 Column 1
Column 2Row 2 Column 2
Column 3Row 2 Column 3
```

Is it default behaviour?
What's up? How to force jQuery table being normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `data-mode's`' by default it is `reflow`, wherein it collapses the table columns into a stacked presentation that looks like blocks of label/data pairs for each row. This behavior is evident only in mobile devices, however in deskop/tablet this will look like a normal table.

Large tables with lots of columns don't fit on smaller screens, hence there is another mode called as `columntoggle` which allows user to toggle the columns.

However in order to have default table structure as seen in desktop browser either get rid of `data-role` attribute or set `data-role='none'`

Put `data-mode="columntoggle"`

```
<table data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="columntoggle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
            <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add the following styles to hide the column button:

```
.ui-table-columntoggle-btn { display: none;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/CGAn4/1/)

Comment: Almost what I want except no need "Columns" button. How to hide it?

Comment: Evidently columntogglemode without Columns button looks the same as non-jQuery' table for sure. But it has methods / properties / events etc as the jQuery object - that's why I don't want to work with HTML-only table here

Comment: A workaround I can think of is hide the button using css, i've updated the fiddle. Please check.